# A confusion about the condition in Hurwitz’s theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

In conway’s book GTM11, the author gave a version of Hurwitz’ theorem

> Let $G$ be a region and suppose the sequence ${f_n}$ in $H(G)$ converges to $f$.If $f\not\equiv 0$,$\overline{B}(a;R)\subset G$,and $f(z)\ne 0$ for $\lvert z-a\rvert=R$ then there is an integer $N$ such that for $n\geq N$,$f$ and $f_n$ have the same number of zeros in $B(a;R)$.

I don’t think we should let $G$ be a region, it seems that $G$ open is enough,does it?

Answer (score 0):

The result indeed holds also if $G$ is not assumed to be connected (but still open).

To prove it, let us decompose $G=\sqcup_\mathbb{N} G_i$, where $G_i$ are the (open) maximal path-connected subset of $G$. In particular, $\overline{B(a,r)}$ must be contained in one of those connected components, $G_j$. It is then trivial to see that the statement can be rewritten in terms of $G_j$, thus taking us back to the connected case.